# passport.authenticate('facebook') method not call + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, authentication, passport-facebook

I have a NodeJS project in which I have to log in with the facebook app.

I am following the http://mherman.org/blog/2013/11/10/social-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/#.WecMnhOCw3h link, and if I run into demo project, it works fine.

but in case of my project, it gives error -
**undefined is not a function**

below is my user.js code -

> var passport = require('passport');
>   var config = require('./oauth.js');

```
  var facebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
     delete user.password;
     done(null, user);
 });

 passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
     done(null, obj);
 });

 passport.use(new facebookStrategy({
         clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
         clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
         callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,

         passReqToCallback: true
     }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
         process.nextTick(function() {
             return done(null, profile);
         });
     }

 ));

 router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
 router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
     passport.authenticate('facebook'),
     function(req, res) {
         res.redirect('/');
     });
```

please help me to resolve my problem, the same error arises in case of google plus login "**undefined is not a function**".

---

Comment: Where is passport declaration like this `var passport = require('passport');`?

Comment: yes, I already declare it in user.js file.

Comment: You have to declare it in every JS file you want to use it.

Comment: And the same for `router`

Comment: I have declared it in every JS file I want to use and the same for the router, but no impact.

Comment: I don't know why "undefined is not a function" error occurs always, please help me to resolve it and thanks for your reply.